# Running Simple "Clear" Script Without Signing In (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

New to java, as well as scripting in google. 
I am a graduate student, running a tabletop (emergency management exercise) event in a few weeks.

I have created a spreadsheet in which I have multiple participants rating their organizational performance. Part of that ranking involves a process where the participants will need to enter numbers into 4 cells which then spits out a result. I need those 4 cells to clear upon the press of a button, so i have poked around and found a script that does what i need it to do:

```
function clearRangeG1() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('G1 2x2');
  sheet.getRange('C18:E18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M18:P18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('C28:E28').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M28:P28').clearContent();
}

function clearRangeG2() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('G2 2x2');
  sheet.getRange('C18:E18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M18:P18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('C28:E28').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M28:P28').clearContent();
}


function clearRangeG3() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('G3 2x2');
  sheet.getRange('C18:E18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M18:P18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('C28:E28').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M28:P28').clearContent();
}


function clearRangeG4() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('G4 2x2');
  sheet.getRange('C18:E18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M18:P18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('C28:E28').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M28:P28').clearContent();
}
```

This works PERFECTLY, none of the code needs to be changed; however, if I am not signed into a google account, I cannot run or use the CLEAR button I have created.

I have looked into this issue, and I have come across information that has lead me to believe there is a way for me to create an API or add on that can run a token so that the button always functions believing my account is activating the submission.

Is this information accurate? Is there actually a way to run a script without needing to sign in? The only thing i need is for this clear button to work for my workshop participants, who may not all have google accounts. If this is indeed possible, could someone direct me towards a proper resource for doing so? I have investigated "OAuth2 Authorization" but the subject seems like it could take me a day or two to sort through. I am really crunched for time, and I do not wish to investigate this further if the process is simple something google does not allow.

Comment: You actually have a button that does this? Is it a custom menu? 
Did you try to share your spreadsheet to `anyone with the link` and to set "Who has access to this app" to `Anyone, even anonymous`? You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) how to do that. And, of course, you always have the option to create a single generic account to be used during the workshop, and give access only to that account.

Comment: Yes, I do have a button that does this. It is a very simple box with text inside, created by "adding a drawing". I have assigned the posted script to this drawing, and whenever i click on this drawing, it clears the data from the designated cells (C18:E18, M18:P18, etc).   I have shared the spreadsheet to "anyone with the link", and I can access all domains of the spreadsheet that I need to while not signed in. Everything in the spreadsheet functions as needed except the button.

Comment: I had not thought about creating a generic account that can be used during the workshop.... Perhaps transferring ownership of the sheet to a new account and sharing that account with the participants might be the best way to go....